# SQL Query: How to filter for each set of value in the column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Currently i am using SQL Fiddle to insert the below statment.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
rn int,
pc varchar(25),
pc1 varchar(25),
grp varchar(25),
e_id varchar(25)
);

INSERT INTO table1
(rn, pc, pc1, grp, e_id)
VALUES(111, 'A1', 'A1', '175', '100');

INSERT INTO table1
(rn, pc, pc1, grp, e_id)
VALUES(111, 'A1', 'A1', '100', '90');

INSERT INTO table1
(rn, pc, pc1, grp, e_id)
VALUES(112, 'B1', 'B1', '101', '90');

INSERT INTO table1
(rn, pc, pc1, grp, e_id)
VALUES(112, 'B1', 'B1', '100', '90');

INSERT INTO table1
(rn, pc, pc1, grp, e_id)
VALUES(112, 'B1', 'B1', '100', '90');

INSERT INTO table1
(rn, pc, pc1, grp, e_id)
VALUES(113, 'C1', 'C1', '100', '90');

**As you can see there are 2 distinct rn numbers.**

    select *
    from table1 
    where rn in(select rn from table1 group by rn having count(*)>1)
    AND (pc = pc1)
    AND grp in (select max(grp) from table1)
    AND e_id in( select min(e_id) from table1)
```

My current query is able to find the correct row based on the condition,

**QN: how to make the conditions work for each set of rn?**.

Thus the result shld have one row for 111 and one row for 112.

I tried searching foreach but could not find a good solution.

****QN2: I have added a extra 1 row with one rn only. My out output with the previous qns should be**

```
RN  PC  PC1 GRP E_ID
111 A1  A1  175 100
112 B1  B1  101 90
113 C1  C1  100 90 --> this row with 1 rn should also output
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is the question?

Comment: `group by rn` ? `select distinct(rn) from table1...` ?

Comment: @scrowler i tried to add grp by rn, my output is still 1 rn

Comment: Please pick a single platform and review tags before using them. Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
select rn, grp, e_id
from table1 
where rn in (select rn from table1 group by rn having count(*)>1)
AND (pc = pc1)
GROUP BY rn
HAVING grp = max(grp) AND e_id = min(e_id)
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d6a5/14

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table1
WHERE  pc = pc1
group by rn having max(grp) AND min(e_id)
```

[sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c45014/3)

but I not really sure what you want, cause max GRP and min E_ID is different records, I assume the priority goes to max grp follow by min e_id.

Query 2 without using having

```
SELECT * from table1
WHERE  pc = pc1
group by rn
order by rn, grp asc, e_id desc
```

Comment: Yes it needs to be more than 1 then max grp then min e_id. In this order

Comment: so does this query help with what you want? if not please post the expected output

Comment: i added my output, in this case i should just remove the count right?

Comment: @ah_hua, is there a way to do it without using having?

Comment: @ps4one, yes, change it to order by. Anyway why having is not your preference? it's like where for group by

Answer (score 0):

```
select rn, max(pc),max(pc1),max(grp),max(e_id) 
from table1 
group by rn;
```

Since '90' > '100' you need to cast to - for example - int if you want the "largest" one:

```
select rn, max(pc),max(pc1),max(grp),max(cast(e_id as int)) 
from table1 
group by rn;

+------+---------+----------+----------+------------------------+
| rn   | max(pc) | max(pc1) | max(grp) | max(cast(e_id as int)) |
+------+---------+----------+----------+------------------------+
|  111 | A1      | A1       | 175      |                    100 |
|  112 | B1      | B1       | 101      |                     90 |
|  113 | C1      | C1       | 100      |                     90 |
+------+---------+----------+----------+------------------------+
```

Choose aggregate functions (such as max) dependent on what you want from "duplicate" rows.